# iOS automatically converting dialed number

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing code to make calls from the app.I am in India. It works fine for non toll free numbers. But for some number such as 18601231000 for BigBasket it is converting the number as +1(860)1231000 which when dialed comes as wrong number.But for numbers starting with 1800 it is coming fine. Here is my code snippet.

```
 private func dialNumber(phoneNumber:String) {

 let phoneUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)")!
 let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
 if(application.canOpenURL(phoneUrl))
 {
    application.openURL(phoneUrl)
 }
 self.ratingLabel.text = "Rate (self.selectedProvider!.providerName)' Customer Care"
 callCenter.callEventHandler = {(call:CTCall!) in

 switch call.callState {
 case CTCallStateConnected:
       break
 case CTCallStateDisconnected: 
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "ctCall")
       break
 default:
       break
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the country code explicitly if it wasn't added by the user?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because `Dial Assist` is on in `Settings` > `Phone`. Try turning it off.